# CodeIgniter : Setting up jQuery and post data to Controller using jQuery

Tags: codeigniter

I added

```
<script type="text/javasript" src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

in **application/views/templatess/header.php** and to post data to **Controller** using jQuery I wrote

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/projects/create',
            data: {
                pro_name : $('#pro_name').val()
            },
            success:function (data) {
                $("#log_msg").html(data);
            }          
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

in my view file: **application/views/project/create.php** and the controller exists in **application/controllers/projects.php**

In my view named **create.php** the complete code is:

```
<label for="pro_name">Project Name</label>
<input type="input" id="pro_name" name="pro_name" />
<br />
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Create" />

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/projects/create',
            data: {
                email : $('#pro_name').val()
            },
            success:function (data) {
                $("#log_msg").html(data);
            }          
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

and my controller named projects contains

```
class Projects extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('projects_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('html');

        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        echo $this->input->post('pro_name');

        $data['title'] = 'SPARCS | Create Project';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pro_name', 'Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pro_client', 'Client', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pro_loc_city', 'City', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pro_loc_state', 'State', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pro_size', 'Project Size', 'required');      
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pro_desc', 'Description', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);   
            $this->load->view('projects/create');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }
        else
        {
            // If project name already exists?

            $query = $this->projects_model->if_exists($this->input->post('pro_name'));

            if ( sizeof($query) == 0) {

                //$this->projects_model->set_project();             
                $data['message'] = 'Add successfully';

            } else {

                $data['message'] = 'Project name already exists';
            }

            $this->load->view('projects/log_message', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

But browser says `$ is not defined`

Now please let me know how to setup jQuery in **CodeIgniter** and what is the correct way to pass data to the **controller** and also show response send back from the **controller**

Comment: Where in the browser does it say `$ is not defined`? Are you sure your jQuery path is correct?

Comment: In firebug, yes jquery is located at root/js/jquery.js I saw view source and when clicked and it is correct and if i clicked it show the js file

Comment: I recommend that you change the url in your ajax request from `/projects/create` to `<?= site_url('projects/create'); ?>`

Comment: I also follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051059/codeigniter-and-javascript-jquery-library but same error shows $ is not defined

Comment: Okay I fix it we should avoid to use <?= instead we should use <?php echo "your_script_here";?> So I replace <?=base_url()?> with <?php echo base_url();?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that somewhere in your code, jQuery is being set into "[safe mode](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)"?

Try wrapping your logic in an anonymous function, like this:

```
​(function($) {
    // insert logic here
})(jQuery)​
```

Whatever is in this function is guaranteed to work with `$` as a shortcut for `jQuery`.